# What is the global file to add logic for all pages in Next.js's app directory?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

What is the main (global) file for a `useEffect` for all pages? Before in Next.js, you could use `useEffect` in `_app.tsx`, and it would affect all pages. Example:

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  useEffect(() => {
     console.log("Hello!")
   )}

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Title</title>
      </Head>

    </>
  );
};
```

And on all pages, you could see the `console.log`. Now using Next.js with the `app` directory, in which file can you use global `useEffect`? Because you can't use useEffect in server files for example, in `layout.tsx`.

Comment: You can render client component in your layout.tsx, and implement your effects in that client component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read on the [Upgrade Guide](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/upgrade-guide), `pages/_app.js` and `pages/_document.js` have been replaced with a single `app/layout.js` root layout.

So you can put your `useEffect` in `app/layout.js` and make it a client component with `"use client"` at the top (knowing that this wouldn't prevent other parts of the app to be server components):

```js
// app/layout.js

"use client";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  
  useEffect(() => {
     console.log("Hello!")
  }, []);

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

But say you don't want your root layout to be a client component, you could do as below, for example, using a separate component:

```js
// SomeGlobalComponent.js

"use client";

export default function SomeGlobalComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
     console.log("Hello!")
  }, []);

  return <></>;
}
```

```js
// app/layout.js

import SomeGlobalComponent from "./SomeGlobalComponent";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <SomeGlobalComponent />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```